# Uploading photos to dropbox

Tags: photos, dropbox

Have Samsung Galaxy  Tab 3.
All of a sudden when I send photo to dropbox to upload doesn't work.
I check dropbox and have the message "waiting to upload", but never loads.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using latest version of Dropbox app.
2. Try to clean Dropbox app data and cache using Application Manager, to do so go to: `Settings > Application manager > Dropbox` hit `Clear data & Clear cache` this will clear your account information and cached data stored on your device. After this just log in to Dropbox with your account once again and it should work.